# App Store Connect: Change subscription price for new subscribers

Tags: app-store-connect, storekit

I want to raise the price of my subscription in my iOS app. Because I think it would be unfair to existing subscribers to charge them more than they have signed up for, I'd only like to set the new price for NEW subscriptions - I want users that have subscribed prior to the change to continue being able to pay the old price in the future renewal cycles.

Now I am extremely confused by the App Store Connect interface on that. It says

> Choose the date you want your price change to begin. Anyone in the
> selected country or regions who subscribes on or after this date will
> pay the new price.

However, in other places I have seen popups by Apple notifying subscribers of other apps that the price will change and they have to opt-in to the new price.

Where exactly can I tick/untick an option that says something like "do not raise the price for current subscribers"? Or do I have to pass that in code somewhere?

I understand it seems to be an option (or the default) to also apply the new price to existing customers but I do not want to do that at all, I want them to keep the old price but apply a new price to new subscribers.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this link may help you.
ref: https://help.apple.com/app-store-connect/?lang=en#/devc9870599e

pls see **Increase the price of an auto-renewable subscription** section

### **1、The follow option may help you "do not raise the price for current subscribers"**

> Choose an option for subscribers paying the current price shown in App
> Store Connect:
>
> A: Keep the current price for existing subscribers. Anyone who
> subscribed before the start date of this price change won’t be
> affected. Subscribers whose subscription expires can resubscribe at
> the preserved price within 60 days of expiration.
>
> B: Apply the price change to existing subscribers who are paying the
> price of your subscription currently displayed on the App Store. App
> Store Connect will provide an indication if consent is required (or if
> they'll simply be notified) for each territory. If you have customer
> groups that have had their prices preserved and your change is
> scheduled for the future, keep in mind that circumstances may change
> and consent will be required based on the conditions of the customer
> at the time of the increase. You are responsible for ensuring you
> understand when consent will be required.

### **2、The follow reason is why you see "price raised tips" in other apps**

> Consent needed If any of the following applies, subscribers must
> consent to the price increase before their next renewal date in order
> for the subscription to renew. Apple will automatically contact them
> by email to request consent, or by push notification.
>
> The subscriber is located in a region that requires consent for any
> price changes.
>
> The price increase is:
>
> More than 50% of the current price; and
>
> The difference in price exceeds approximately $5 United States Dollar
> (USD) per period for non-annual subscriptions, or $50 USD per year for
> annual subscriptions.
>
> International equivalents for prices not in USD are based on current
> exchange rates with the specific thresholds which are subject to
> change at any time based on changes in foreign exchange rates. View a
> list of thresholds per territory.
>
> The subscriber already had a price increase for that subscription
> within the past 12 months.